# Why do yogis prefer bathing with cold water?

Tags: customs, spirituality, yogi

I have been reading in many autobiographies and biographies about the preference of cold water for bathing even during harsh winters. So my question is: for the person on the path of spirituality does this have any significance or is it a mere custom/ritual being followed by all yogis?

Any references from scriptures would be preferred in the answer.

Comment: probably because it trains your mind to withdraw from bodily senses.

Comment: Not a religious question per se, biological. If you are bathed in cold water when you are a baby and as a young child, your body and nerves prefer cold water for bathing. If you are bathed in hot or warm water, your body and nerves prefer that.

Comment: You become awake with a jolt & dispels dark remnants from sleep!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably because hot (specially boiled) water isn't considered pure. So, bathing with/in that water will not be purifying.

See for example Manu Smriti 2.61:

> अनुष्णाभिरफेनाभिरद्भिस्तीर्थेन धर्मवित् ।
>  शौचेप्सुः
> सर्वदाऽचामेदेकान्ते प्रागुदङ्मुखः ॥ ६१ ॥
>
> anuṣṇābhiraphenābhiradbhistīrthena dharmavit |
>  śaucepsuḥ
> sarvadā'cāmedekānte prāgudaṅmukhaḥ || 61 ||
>
> One who knows his duties, when desiring cleanliness, should always
> sip, through the proper receptacle, water which is neither hot nor
> frothy,—in solitude, with his face towards the North or the East.—(61)

Here it is prohibited to perform Achamana using hot water implying that hot water isn't considered pure.

The [commentator Medhatithi](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc145651.html) says that here prohibition is on boiled water and not water that has naturally turned hot due to climatic condition.

> **Hot’ here stands for boiled;** elsewhere we read that the sipping should be done ‘with unboiled water.’ So that the prohibition docs not
> apply to such water as is naturally hot, or has imbibed the beat of
> the hot atmosphere.
>
> ‘Froth’ is meant to include ‘bubbles’ also, as elsewhere we read that
> ‘the water should be free from froth and bubbles.’
>
> The terms ‘through the proper receptacle’ and ‘one who knows his
> duties’ have been added only for the purpose of filling up the metre.
>
> ‘Desiring cleanliness’—seeking to attain cleanliness, i.e., purity.
> The sense is that without the sipping of water he can never be clean.

Since during winter getting hot water is not possible without heating/boiling it hence the only option is to bath in the cold water.

This does not mean that it's compulsory for everybody to do the same. I have read elsewhere that diseased or old persons (i.e. who are incapable of taking cold water baths) can bath with warm water or just sponging the body with a wet towel will also do.

And, it also does not mean that taking bath in water that is naturally hot isn't purifying. This is mentioned in one of the following verses quoted in the book "Dharma Bindu" (hosted at Kamakoti.org):

> *Samudra Snaana:*
>
> The general saying is:
>
> Ashvattham manda vaaretu Saagaram parvani sprushet,
>  Ashvattha
> Saagarao sevyou kadaachana/
>
> (Ashvattha tree is worthy of touch on Saturdays and so is Samudra on
> Pournamis; indeed both these are worthy of worship and not to be
> touched indiscriminately)
>
> Bharadwaaja Muni instructs:
>
> Krishnaangaara chaturdashyaamyobdhou snaanam samacharet,
>  Tasya
> janma sahasreshu sarvam paapam pranashyati/
>  Seturnaapekshate
> kaalam nityam snaanam prashasyate,
>  Nishedhah kaalabhedasya
> setoranyatra karhichit/
>
> (Samudra Snaanas on Tuesdays of Krishna Paksha and Chaturdashis would
> destroy sins of thousands of previous births. However Setu snaanas
> could be done without any restrictions of days or times.)
>
> Vyasa Maharshi describes:
>
> Kurukshetram Gayaam Gangaam Prabhaasam Naimisham tathaa,
> Tirthenyetaani sarvaani snaanakaale smaredbudhah /
>  Aaapayeva
> putaah taasaam vahnirvishodhakah,
>  Tasmaatsarveshu kaaleshu
> ushnaanbhah paavanam smritam/
>
> (All the persons of virtue should bathe at Kurukshetra, Gaya, Gangaa,
> Prabhasa, Naimisha and while so bathing announce the Sacred names of
> the Places concerned. **While water purifies and is clean, Agni
> purifies far more and hence hot water baths are stated to be more
> preferable at all the places and times)**

Answer (score 1):

The article [Classical Yoga: The Right Conditions](https://isha.sadhguru.org/in/en/wisdom/article/classical-yoga-the-right-conditions) offers the following excerpt—from Sadhguru Jaggi Vasudev's discourse at the Isha Hatha Yoga School's 21-week Hatha Yoga Teacher Training program—as a part of some tips and guidelines to get the most out of one's Hatha Yoga practice:

> #### #3 Cold Water
>
> Before beginning your practice, it is always best to be immersed in or to allow a certain volume of water which is about five to eight degree centigrade lower than room temperature to flow over you. If this happens, the pores between the skin cells open up, and that’s important for practicing yoga because we want the cellular structure of the body to be charged with a different dimension of energy. Why one person seems to be far more alive than the other is essentially because of this. Once your cellular structure is charged with energy, it remains youthful for a very long time.

In the video [Are You Showering the Right Way?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iiygw1TKXH0), Sadhguru speaks about how one can have an optimal shower. A part of the video is an elaboration on the above extract, but there is also some information that is relevant for those who are not necessarily yogis or sadhakas.

Answer (score 1):

There are some verses in the Purāṇas in this regard that encourage a Cold Water bath.

#### 1. Śiva Purāṇa: [Verse 2.1.13.(10-11)](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc225981.html)

> रवेर्दिने तथा श्राद्धे संक्रान्तौ ग्रहणे तथा । 
> महादाने तथा तीर्थे
> ह्युपवासदिने तथा ॥ १० ॥
>  अशौचेप्यथवा प्राप्ते न स्नायादुष्णवारिणा ।
>  यथा
> साभिमुखंस्नायात्तीर्थादौ भक्तिमान्नरः ॥ ११ ॥
>
> > 10. & 11. Hot water bath shall be avoided on sundays, Śrāddha days, Saṅkrānti days, at the times of eclipse, on days of Great Charity and
> >     fast, in holy centres and during the days of impurity due to death or
> >     birth in the family. In the holy ponds and rivers one shall take bath
> >     facing the east with great devotion.
>
> English Translation by J.L. Shastri

**So, as per the Śiva Purāṇa, certain days are forbidden for a hot-water bath.**

#### 2. Padma Purāṇa: [Verse 6.64.(36b & 37a)](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-padma-purana/d/doc365641.html)

> शीतांबुना गृहे स्नानात्निर्मलं देहमाप्नुयात् ॥ ३६.ख ॥
>  उष्णोदकं
> परित्यज्य स्नानं वै पौष्करं लभेत् । ३७.क ।
>
> > 36. b. By bathing with cold water in his house he would obtain a spotless, body.
>
> > 37. a. By avoiding a bath with hot water he would get the fruit of a bath at Puṣkara.
>
> English Translation by N.A Deshpande

**As per the Padma-Purāṇa, specifically during the Cāturmāsya, a hot water bath is discouraged, while a Cold water bath gives a faultless body.**